# Delay an action within an ActionListener?

Tags: java, delay, actionlistener

**What I Want To Do:** I want to add a delay between two actions within an ActionListener so I tried using the code below:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

              System.out.println("Hello");

              try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
              } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              }

              System.out.println("Goodbye");
         }
    };
```

**The Problem:** All that happened was that the JButton would just freeze for the amount of time that I delayed the action.

**My Question:** I need to know how to delay so that it will print "Hello" and then 1000 milliseconds (or 1 second) later, I want it to print "Goodbye".

Comment: See swing documentation on background tasks: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok I got it, though it seems a little much for such a simple task.  It would be so much simpler to just use Thread.sleep(), but that delays the whole program.

Comment: It doesn't delay the whole program, it just delays the event dispatch thread.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh.  There are still no simple ways to do this though.  I just don't want my code to become a jumbled mess.

Comment: Don't write a jumbled mess then :) Can't you just use a javax.swing.Timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this straightforwardly with a `javax.swing.Timer`:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          System.out.println("Hello");
          new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              System.out.println("Goodbye");
            }
          }).start();
     }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!  I'd up vote, but I lack the reputation.

Comment: Is there a proper way to only go through the timer's ActionListener only once?

Comment: Just add a boolean variable to the class to hold the state of whether the button has been pressed, and check/set it appropriately.